# Update S3 KMS key on an object using server side encryption

Tags: ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am working on a feature where a customer can update their KMS key in our platform so that they are using their KMS key to encrypt data instead of one generated by us. The way it works is when a customer signs up, we generate a KMS key for them and upload the objects using that key. If the customer wants to provide their own key, I want to be able to update this key without having to pull down the data and re-upload with the new key.

```rb
def enc_client
  Aws::S3::Encryption::Client.new(
    kms_client: Aws::KMS::Client.new(region: 'us-east-1'),
    kms_key_id: ENV['MY_PRIVATE_KEY']
  )
end

def s3_client
  enc_client.client
end

bucket = "my_bucket_name"
key = "path/12345abcde/preview.html"
copy_source = "/#{key}"
server_side_encryption = "aws:kms"

# This returns the object with the key present. If I go in the AWS client and manually add or remove the key, it will update on this call.
resp = s3_client.get_object(bucket: bucket, key: key)

#<struct Aws::S3::Types::GetObjectOutput
 body=#<StringIO:0x000000000bb45108>,
 delete_marker=nil,
 accept_ranges="bytes",
 expiration=nil,
 restore=nil,
 last_modified=2019-04-12 15:40:09 +0000,
 content_length=19863445,
 etag="\"123123123123123123123123123123-1\"",
 missing_meta=nil,
 version_id=nil,
 cache_control=nil,
 content_disposition="inline; filename=\"preview.html\"",
 content_encoding=nil,
 content_language=nil,
 content_range=nil,
 content_type="text/html",
 expires=nil,
 expires_string=nil,
 website_redirect_location=nil,
 server_side_encryption="aws:kms",
 metadata={},
 sse_customer_algorithm=nil,
 sse_customer_key_md5=nil,
 ssekms_key_id="arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:123456789123:key/222b222b-bb22-2222-bb22-222bbb22bb2b",
 storage_class=nil,
 request_charged=nil,
 replication_status=nil,
 parts_count=nil,
 tag_count=nil>

new_ssekms_key_id = "arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:123456789123:key/111a111a-aa11-1111-aa11-111aaa11aa1a"


resp = s3_client.copy_object(bucket: bucket, key: key, copy_source: copy_source, ssekms_key_id: ssekms_key_id)
Aws::S3::Errors::InvalidArgument: Server Side Encryption with AWS KMS managed key requires HTTP header x-amz-server-side-encryption : aws:kms
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.6.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call'


resp = s3_client.copy_object(bucket: bucket, key: key, copy_source: copy_source, ssekms_key_id: ssekms_key_id, server_side_encryption: server_side_encryption)
Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied
from /usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.6.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:15:in `call'
```

I would like to be able to update the kms id do a new one on the server side

Answer (score 0):

`copy_source = "/#{key}"` is incorrect.  The value should be `"/#{bucket}/#{key}"`.

The service is interpreting the first element of your key path as the name of a bucket -- probably someone else's bucket.